# How to use switch statement to match against passed generic type and return object[]

Tags: c#, generics, types, switch-statement

I am a tester with a little programming knowledge, but I can't get this to work.

I am creating a base class for my integration tests (BaseIntegrationTest.cs). It uses generics to accept the `DbContext` and `Repository` Types that the particular test class is targeting. The base class sets up database context and connections and creates instances of the appropriate repository/controller classes.

```
    class BaseIntegrationTest <TContext, TRepo> where TContext : DbContext where TRepo : BaseRepository
    {
        ...

    }
```

Besides the `DbContext` and `Repository` Types that are potentially unique for each test class, we also have to determine the DatabaseConnectionString and the signature of the constructor for the target Repository class (as the number of parameters sent to the constructor can vary).

I determine these values based on the passed generic types. `TContext` defines which DbConnectionString I use, and `TRepo` defines which Repository constructor signature to use. To define these things I have added a private static inner class `GenericTypeHelper`. My `BaseIntegrationTest` class then looks something like this...

```
...

namespace OurProduct.Tests.IntegrationTests
{
    class BaseIntegrationTest <TContext, TRepo> where TContext : DbContext where TRepo : BaseRepository
    {
        ...

        protected Dictionary<string, string> LocalDbConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        protected TRepo Repository;

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            DefineLocalDbConfigs();
            SetupNewLocalDB();
            Repository = SetupRepository<TContext, TRepo>();
        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            TearDownLocalDB();
        }

        private void DefineLocalDbConfigs()
        {
            ...
            // define LocalDbConfig dictionary and add db configs
            ...
        }

        private void SetupNewLocalDB()
        {
            ...
            // set up LocalDb databases
            ...
        }

        public RepoType SetupRepository<DbContextType, RepoType>() where DbContextType : DbContext where RepoType : BaseRepository
        {
            var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            configBuilder.AddInMemoryCollection(LocalDbConfig);
            var configuration = configBuilder.Build();

            var dbBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContextType>();
            dbBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString(GenericTypeHelper.DbConnStringForDbContext[typeof(DbContextType)]));

            var context = (DbContextType)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(DbContextType), new object[] { dbBuilder.Options });
            var logger = Mock.Of<ILogger<RepoType>>();
            var clock = new SystemClock();

            var commonLogger = Mock.Of<ILogger<CommonRepository>>();
            var commonRepo = new CommonRepository(configuration, commonLogger, clock);

            var repoConstrParamObjArr = GenericTypeHelper.GetRepoConstrParamObjArr(context, logger, clock, commonRepo);
            return (RepoType)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(RepoType), repoConstrParamObjArr);
        }

        private void TearDownLocalDB()
        {
            foreach (var dbConnDefn in LocalDbConfig)
            {
                ...
                // open, set offline, close, dispose database
                ...
            }
        }

        private static class GenericTypeHelper
        {
            internal static readonly Dictionary<Type, string> DbConnStringForDbContext = new Dictionary<Type, string>
            {
                { typeof(DataContextA), "DB1" },
                { typeof(DataContextB), "DB2" },
                { typeof(DataContextC), "DB3" },
                { typeof(DataContextD), "DB1" },
                { typeof(DataContextE), "DB2" },
                { typeof(DataContextF), "DB3" }
            };

            internal static object[] GetRepoConstrParamObjArr<DbContextType, RepoType>(
                    DbContextType context,
                    ILogger<RepoType> logger,
                    SystemClock clock,
                    CommonRepository commonRepo)
                        where DbContextType : DbContext 
                        where RepoType : BaseRepository
                => typeof(RepoType) switch
                {
                    // these give compile error... CS0150: A constant value is expected
                    typeof(DataRepositoryA) => new object[] { context, logger, clock, commonRepo },
                    typeof(DataRepositoryB) => new object[] { context, logger, clock },
                    // these give compile error... CS8121: An expression of type 'Type' cannot be handled by a pattern of type 'DataRepositoryC'
                    DataRepositoryC         => new object[] { context, logger, clock, commonRepo },
                    DataRepositoryD         => new object[] { context, logger, clock },
                    _ => new object[] { }
                };

        }

    }
}
```

This inner class gives me compile errors (as noted in the comments) where I try and use the switch statement to compare the generic `RepoType` to the listed possible Repository class types that will be passed into `BaseIntegrationTest`. Is there some way I can use the clean switch functionality to match on the generic Type?

Comment: `RepoType` is a generic type parameter, not an instance of the `Type` class (under normal conventions it would be called `TRepo` or similar to make this clear). `switch` operators on object instances, so you'd need to write `switch (typeof(RepoType))`. However, the arms of a switch statement have to be constant expressions, and `typeof(...)` is no a constant, therefore you cann't use a switch statement/expression. You'll have to use a chain of if/else if, or use a `Dictionary<Type, object[]>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @Matthew Watson's answer (with help from @The General) was clever and it solved my compile issues, it did not run as desired. `default(RepoType)` returns an expected default value of the correct Type for basic types, however for non-basic types it returns `null`. This means the switch statement matches on the default `_ => new object[] { }` regardless of which `RepoType` I generically pass in.

I did however find a solution through the use of `nameof()` which suits my needs.

Original code giving me compile errors...

```
    internal static object[] GetRepoConstrParamObjArr<DbContextType, RepoType>(
            DbContextType context,
            ILogger<RepoType> logger,
            SystemClock clock,
            CommonRepository commonRepo)
                where DbContextType : DbContext 
                where RepoType : BaseRepository
        => typeof(RepoType) switch
        {
            // these give compile error... CS0150: A constant value is expected
            typeof(DataRepositoryA) => new object[] { context, logger, clock, commonRepo },
            typeof(DataRepositoryB) => new object[] { context, logger, clock },
            // these give compile error... CS8121: An expression of type 'Type' cannot be handled by a pattern of type 'DataRepositoryC'
            DataRepositoryC         => new object[] { context, logger, clock, commonRepo },
            DataRepositoryD         => new object[] { context, logger, clock },
            _ => new object[] { }
        };
```

Solution which compiles and runs as expected...

```
    internal static object[] GetRepoConstrParamObjArr<DbContextType, RepoType>(
            DbContextType context,
            ILogger<RepoType> logger,
            SystemClock clock,
            CommonRepository commonRepo)
                where DbContextType : DbContext 
                where RepoType : BaseRepository
        => typeof(RepoType).Name switch
        {
            nameof(DataRepositoryA) => new object[] { context, logger, clock, commonRepo },
            nameof(DataRepositoryB) => new object[] { context, logger, clock },
            nameof(DataRepositoryC) => new object[] { context, logger, clock, commonRepo },
            nameof(DataRepositoryD) => new object[] { context, logger, clock },
            _                       => new object[] { }
        };
```